# Django: Exclude users in M2M

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to exclude the Users that are inside the `DocumentUsers` table:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DocumentUsers(models.Model):    
    pnr = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)


users = User.objects.exclude(username__in=[user for user in DocumentUsers.objects.all()])
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with:

```
User.objects.filter(documentusers=None)
```

We here thus perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the table with the `DocumentUsers` records, and thus only retrieve `User`s for which this `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is `NULL`/`None`.